# Embedding a javascript variable within a jsp request.getAttribute method

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is my javascript code for populating a modal, on click of a table row. What I want to do is, to get the object's various properties from the struts action in the backend. But to get the exact index of the product to be fetched from the list of products, I need to embed the clicked row's id into the request.getAttribute method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('table tbody tr  td').on('click', function () {
     $("#productModal").modal("show");

     $("#prodDet1").text("ID : " + $(this).closest('tr').children()  [1].textContent);

     $("#prodDet2").text("Name : " + $(this).closest('tr').children()[2].textContent);

     //This is where I store the table row id (in var foo)
     var foo = $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent;

     // I want to do something like this
     $("#prodDet4").text("Stock count : " + <%= request.getAttribute("productList.get(" + foo + ").stock") %> );                                          


    document.getElementById("prodDet3").src = "http://localhost:8080/Rest/Flipkart/ImageServices/Image/" + $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
 });

</script>
```

So how do I embed the foo's value into the getAttribute call?

Comment: You don't. JSP is executed before anything ever gets sent to the client.

Comment: Is there another way for me to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: Expose the data to JS so you don't need to use a scriptlet (bad practice anyway); there are a variety of ways that could be done.

Comment: Could you please post as to how to do that.... been at this for quite a while.. its the last piece to my puzzle.... yet I am stuck :)

Comment: Then a) remove the DOM accesses (textContent and getElementById) and b) add jQuery tag, then c) look up Ajax jquery